# How to aggregate nested JavaScript object by property?

Tags: javascript

I have the following JavaScript object:

```
var example = [{
    country: "US",
    things: {
      weather: 'cloudy'
    }
  },
  {
    country: "US",
    things: {
      resource: 'lead',
      weather: 'sunny'
    }
  },
  {
    country: "MX",
    things: {
      weather: 'sunny'
    }
  },
  {
    country: "MX",
    things: {
      resource: 'gold',
      weather: 'sunny'
    }
  },
  {
    country: "MX",
    things: {
      resource: 'copper'
    }
  },
]
```

I would like to convert to this format via aggregation.

```
var out = [{
    country_code: 'US',
    things: {
      resource: ['lead'],
      weather: ['cloudy', 'sunny']
    }
  },
  {
    country_code: 'MX',
    things: {
      resource: ['gold', 'copper'],
      weather: ['sunny'],
    }
  }

]
```

I have tried to look into using combinations of reduce and map to no avail.  It would be great if this example can also serve as a jumping off point for general strategies for data manipulation that may or may not involve the use of the array methods.

Comment: what you have tried so far? can you post your code here

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use `reduce` to iterate over the objects to compile your new object, piecing together the things you want:

```js
const example = [{
    country: "US",
    things: {
      weather: 'cloudy'
    }
  },
  {
    country: "US",
    things: {
      resource: 'lead',
      weather: 'sunny'
    }
  },
  {
    country: "MX",
    things: {
      weather: 'sunny'
    }
  },
  {
    country: "MX",
    things: {
      resource: 'gold',
      weather: 'sunny'
    }
  },
  {
    country: "MX",
    things: {
      resource: 'copper'
    }
  },
]

const out = Object.values(
  example.reduce((a, v) => {
    if (!a[v.country]) {
      a[v.country] = {
        country_code: v.country,
        things: {}
      }
    }

    Object.entries(v.things).forEach(([key, value]) => {
      if (!a[v.country].things[key]) {
        a[v.country].things[key] = []
      }

      if (!a[v.country].things[key].includes(value)) {
        a[v.country].things[key].push(value)
      }
    })

    return a
  }, {})
)

console.log(out)
```

Answer (score 1):

This will show you how to use reduce to get the data that you want using reduce

```js
const example = [{
    country: "US",
    things: {
      weather: "cloudy"
    }
  },
  {
    country: "US",
    things: {
      resource: "lead",
      weather: "sunny"
    }
  },
  {
    country: "MX",
    things: {
      weather: "sunny"
    }
  },
  {
    country: "MX",
    things: {
      resource: "gold",
      weather: "sunny"
    }
  },
  {
    country: "MX",
    things: {
      resource: "copper"
    }
  }
];

const output = example.reduce((acc, current) => {
  const index = acc.findIndex(x => x.country === current.country);
  if (index === -1) {
    const newNode = {
      country: current.country,
      things: {
        resource: current.things.resource ? [current.things.resource] : [],
        weather: current.things.weather ? [current.things.weather] : []
      }
    };
    acc.push(newNode);
  } else {
    current.things.resource && acc[index].things.resource.findIndex(x => x === current.things.resource) === -1 && acc[index].things.resource.push(current.things.resource)


    current.things.weather && acc[index].things.weather.findIndex(x => x === current.things.weather) === -1 && acc[index].things.weather.push(current.things.weather)
  }
  return acc;
}, []);

console.log(output);
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use `reduce` function and use `findIndex` to check if the accumulator have the object with `country_code`. If it is there then update the array in `things` object.

```js
var example = [{
    country: "US",
    things: {
      weather: 'cloudy'
    }
  },
  {
    country: "US",
    things: {
      resource: 'lead',
      weather: 'sunny'
    }
  },
  {
    country: "MX",
    things: {
      weather: 'sunny'
    }
  },
  {
    country: "MX",
    things: {
      resource: 'gold',
      weather: 'sunny'
    }
  },
  {
    country: "MX",
    things: {
      resource: 'copper'
    }
  },
]


function finalOut(arr) {
  return arr.reduce(function(acc, curr) {
    let findIndex = acc.findIndex(function(item) {
      return item.country_code === curr.country;
    });
    if (findIndex === -1) {
      acc.push({
        country_code: curr.country,
        things: {
          resource: curr.things.resource ? [curr.things.resource] : [],
          weather: curr.things.weather ? [curr.things.weather] : []
        }
      })
    } else {

      if (curr.things.resource && acc[findIndex].things.resource.indexOf(curr.things.resource) === -1) {
        acc[findIndex].things.resource.push(curr.things.resource);
      }

      if (curr.things.weather && acc[findIndex].things.weather.indexOf(curr.things.weather) === -1) {
        acc[findIndex].things.weather.push(curr.things.weather);
      }

    }

    return acc;
  }, [])
}

console.log(finalOut(example))
```

Answer (score 1):

Use reduce to iterate over all the items and then arrange them in the right format:

```
example.reduce((prev,current)=>{

        let index = prev.findIndex(item => item.country_code == current.country);

        if(index>=0){
            if(current.things.resource && !prev[index].things.resource.includes(current.things.resource))
                prev[index].things.resource.push(current.things.resource);
            if(current.things.weather && !prev[index].things.weather.includes(current.things.weather))
                prev[index].things.weather.push(current.things.weather);
        }else{
            prev.push({
                country_code : current.country,
                things : {
                    weather : current.things.weather ? [current.things.weather] : [],
                    resource : current.things.resource ? [current.things.resource] : []
                }
            });
        }
        return prev;
},[]);
```

Answer (score 1):

1. Build map of country data using [`reduce`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/Reduce)

```js
{
  US: {
    resource: ['lead'],
    weather: ['cloudy', 'sunny'],
  },
  MX: {
    resource: ['gold', 'copper'],
    weather: ['sunny'],
  },
}
```

2. Use [`Object.entries`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/entries) to get an Array of entries from the map

```js
[
  [ 'US', { resource: ['lead'], weather: ['cloudy', 'sunny'] } ],
  [ 'MX', { resource: ['gold', 'copper'], weather: ['sunny'] } ],
]
```

3. Map the Array of entries into an Array of Objects with the desired structure

```js
const buildCountriesMap = data => data.reduce((map, { country, things: { weather, resource } }) => {
  if (!map.hasOwnProperty(country)) {
    map[country] = { resource: [], weather: [] };
  }

  const { resource: mapResource, weather: mapWeather } = map[country];

  if (resource && !mapResource.includes(resource)) {
    mapResource.push(resource);
  }
  if (weather && !mapWeather.includes(weather)) {
    mapWeather.push(weather);
  }

  return map;
}, {});

const merge = data => Object.entries(buildCountriesMap(data))
  .map(([country, things]) => ({ country, things }));

const example = [
  {
    country: 'US',
    things: {
      weather: 'cloudy',
    },
  },
  {
    country: 'US',
    things: {
      resource: 'lead',
      weather: 'sunny',
    },
  },
  {
    country: 'MX',
    things: {
      weather: 'sunny',
    },
  },
  {
    country: 'MX',
    things: {
      resource: 'gold',
      weather: 'sunny',
    },
  },
  {
    country: 'MX',
    things: {
      resource: 'copper',
    },
  },
];

console.log(merge(example));
```